# Difference using form's action attribute

Tags: javascript, forms, jsp, struts2

I have a question in my mind that what is the major difference between using various *form actions*

like we have action in our scripting language JavaScript we have action in jQuery.

also in Struts 2 we have action attribute in form and in `submit` also.

So what is the basic purpose and the best used place for them? Hope an example would clear all the difference.

```jsp
<s:form name="xyz" action="xyz" method="post">
```

and

```jsp
 <s:submit action="xyz" />
```

and

```js
 document.getElementById("myForm").action="form_action.jsp";
```

Comment: downvoter please comment for downvote and i guess you might have the eaziest answer that why he downvoted.please mention answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main and *major* difference between then is that the Struts tags are JSP tags and run on server side, while HTML and javascript run on client side (in the browser).

First `action` is an attribute of the Struts tag that accepts OGNL expressions to parse for URL.

The second is just a static text referencing a JSP in the current context.

Comment: and what about action in form and submit? tags

Comment: they are used the same purpose to map Struts actions to them.

Comment: so what is the diffrence they are made for ?as making a same thing for a same purpose is not a good work i guess our java developers have done

Comment: A same thing is different as the same purpose, your developers would better map to the struts action that is able to process the request then forward to JSP.